# I need some help creating a grid based website

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

Here's the layout I want:

![image: Layout]

I'm having some trouble converting it into code.

I've been thinking about bootstrap but I have elements that go across columns and rows and i'm just not sure how to code it and keep everything in the 6x4 grid I have created for the layout.

Another problem in this regard is the responsiveness. The boxes in the grid are supposed to stack when the viewport is made shorter. however this also creates problems when elements use a different number of columns.

Any ideas on how I should approach this?

Comment: You'd need to be more specific about how you wanted to stack the grid items on a narrow screen.  Bootstrap also allows for increasingly small definitions of narrow.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking reading up on how the [bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) works and how you can nest rows within rows.

Here's a rough mockup of how you could acheive your design with bootstrap

```css
.mygrid {
  text-align: center;
}
.mygrid div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="mygrid">

    <!-- Top Half -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="row">1</div>
        <div class="row">2</div>
      </div>  
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        3<br/>
        3.5
      </div> 
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="row">4</div>
        <div class="row">5</div>
      </div>  
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="row">6</div>
        <div class="row">7</div>
      </div>  
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="row">8</div>
        <div class="row">9</div>
      </div>  
    </div>
    
    <!-- Bottom Half -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8">10</div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">11</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">12</div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">13</div>            
        </div>
      </div>  
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        14<br/>
        14.5
      </div> 
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="row">15</div>
        <div class="row">16</div>
      </div> 

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I added the `.mygrid` class just to help set some styles on the grid, but it's not necessary.